# using GD library drawing in php?

Tags: php

the system is `window xp`.now, i  using  GD library to draw a chart set the font path as this:

```
    putenv('GDFONTPATH=c:\windows\Fonts');
    $fontname='arial';
   $bbox=imagettfbbox($font_size,0,$fontname,$button_text);
```

the programme gave me a tip: can't find the font? but in my window xp system, there is a font named `arial` in the `Fonts` file. why ?

test code:

```
 putenv('GDFONTPATH=C:\\WINDOWS\\Fonts');
 $fontname='arial';
$char="test";
$size=20;
$bbox=imagettfbbox($size,0,$fontname,$char);
```

it show `invalidate font filename,`

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you have to use double backslashes, like so: 
`putenv('GDFONTPATH=c:\\windows\\Fonts');`

Comment: i am sorry, it still can't work. i put the test code on the above.

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont know. Did you also try `$fontname='arial.ttf';`? I don't know if it will add the .ttf itself.

Answer (score 0):

GDFONTPATH can't use under window. you should use absolute path directly.